# UglifyJS2 breaks dependency injection in Angular.js application

Tags: angularjs, annotations, minify, gulp-uglify

I have an Angular.js application, that I want to minify.

First of all, I've setup a certain gulp pipeline in order to handle annotations and minifications automatically.

In order to check how well implicit annotations work, I've added annotations using [ngAnnotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) and then ran application with [strict-di](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) options in order to catch all missed annotations. Then I've added comment hints for all missing annotations I've found. After that, everything works great, `ngAnnotate` automatically annotates my code and `strict-di` has no more warnings.

However, when I actually minify my code using [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), it fails to start the application saying that some service wasn't being found.

Here's the actual error message:

> State change error Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tProvider <- t

If I add `mangle: false` option to the `UglifyJS2`, it works fine.

— So the question is, how do I find the culprit and why `strict-di` isn't catching it?

Comment: I answer this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36309546/4775223

Comment: Thanks @WilmerS , but your answer is not answering my specific question. I know how DI works and I'm already using ngAnnotate. The problem is that it doesn't handle all cases and for some reason strict-di doesn't catch those cases either.

Comment: I see. It seems that you have tried what I would try. However, and technically speaking if you are explicitly injecting dependencies then removing ngAnnotate from your pipe shouldn't make a difference. The same error should pop up. if not, then ngAnnotate may have something to do with it.

Comment: If you are not explicitly injecting dependencies then I suggest that you do. I use ngAnnotate as a safeguard. Not as an annotation utility.

Comment: OK, thanks, but I'm going to investigate further. Explicit annotations make code ugly and not DRY. I rather skip this practice, it shouldn't be done by humans.

Comment: Good point. I must agree with you, but chasing bugs in minified code is impossible, and investigating every time this happens is time consuming. If it happens twice that is enough reason to change philosophy until a better solution comes around

Comment: The only problem is that I'm converting a pretty large existing code base. In case of incremental development it shouldn't be a problem. I'm using such strategy for a long time already and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Okay! I've finally managed to sort out this issue.

I'm going to post here a strategy that helped me to efficiently resolve it.

## Strategy

I've had a pretty big code base, everything was in a single JavaScript file. All dependencies, third-party, as well as local, were stated in it and bundled with gulp plugin.

The first thing I did, was to split the code into two files: `vendor.js` and `application.js`. I've moved all third-party dependencies to the first file and left all local dependencies in the second one. After that, I've tried to run my application with `application.js` minified and `vendor.js` unminified. This simple trick helped me to determine that problem was actually with the third-party code and not with my application.

I've had a 34 external dependencies specified at that point, so again, I've created two files `vendor.js` and `vendor-cleared.js` and started to move dependencies from first one into second one (by halves). This time, I've compiled the second one and left first one unminified. After a couple of iterations, I've found a problematic third-party library that wasn't properly annotated.

I've fixed it, and put everything back together again in my `application.js`. After that, my app started to work flawlessly.

---

I hope this simple idea will help you to convert large code base to a properly annotated one and to finally minify it!

After that, just check if minification works properly when you add new dependencies. And don't forget to always use `strict-di`. It doesn't work all the time, but it does a fairly good job.